# "Denied access to network" for my phone only from new router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android, wireless-access-point

Every couple days, my phone (Huawei P30) can't connect to my new router (Asus RT-AX58U) anymore. Resetting the phone's network settings or restarting my router fixes the immediate issue but it comes back.

I've checked the router's logs and found the following:

```
Apr 11 10:56:57 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(499): eth6: Auth PHONES_MAC_ADDRESS, status: Successful (0)
Apr 11 10:56:57 wlceventd: wlceventd_proc_event(464): eth6: Deauth_ind PHONES_MAC_ADDRESS, status: 0, reason: Unspecified reason (1)
```

there were 2000 of auths + deauths within half a minute, so I can understand why the router would block access for the phone, but why is it happening in the first place?

The router is new, but we have another smartphone, some IoT devices and few laptops - and all of those work fine.

I don't want to reset my network configuration every couple of days.

Comment: There's not enough info to state for certain, but if this only occurs on the phone and not other devices, it's likely a firmware issue on the phone _(especially if other Android devices stay connected without issue)_.  If it is an issue with the device, the best place for help would be the [XDA Developer Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) or StackExchange's [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).  However, if this occurs with other devices, it's likely an issue with the router's settings (see router's support page or contact the manufacturer's tech support).

Comment: thx @JW0914 - I never had any issues with this phone on other networks and I also don't have a custom firmware there that's why I was focusing on the router as such, but I'll research a bit more about huawei firmware, thx

Comment: Short of flashing opensource firmware to your router (such as OpenWrt if they support your router), there's not a lot of troubleshooting that can be done on a router's OEM firmware since normal diagnostics & troubleshooting via SSH/serial are likely not supported. The only times I've seen behavior similar to what you describe on the router's side is when there's a typo in the DNS/DHCP config settings of the router (static IP, MAC or hostname of the client device, etc.). Export your router's settings, flash the most recent fw version, and if it still occurs on a fresh fw flash, it's the phone.